# Get a text from Html string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, dom, javascript-objects

Need to extract one key from a string containing HTML doc using JavaScript /NodeJs.

I am getting a HTML Page as response of one service which includes a key, which need to be extracted, the key is inside a  tag and the page is heavily nested , even after converting to JSON also didn't help.

Tried with regular expression that also not fetching all results (since there are many matches with  tag).

The key in  tag is like the following:

```
<script>
$function(){
//some codes
app.init({
//some code
access : {"AccessKey": "dwdfsfcnoidxjbvukv"}

});

//some code
</script>
```

Comment: That questions smells like a hacking attempt. Can you clarify your intentions please ?

Comment: I don't see anything here that looks like NodeJs code. I also see nothing here that does... anything. Mind showing what you have actually tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex `/\{"AccessKey":(.*)\}/`  which I think suitable for this problem.

```
 var data = `<script>
    $function(){
    app.init({
    access : {"AccessKey": "dwdfsfcnoidxjbvukv"}
    });
    </script>`;

    var result = data.match(/\{"AccessKey":(.*)\}/);

    console.log(result[1]);
```